# Trying to get a process name but I get hex instead of text

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

Here's my code (please ignore my 'try' statement, I know..):

```
wchar_t *zGetName(DWORD kPid)
{
    if (!kPid)
        return NULL;
    PROCESSENTRY32W kPE32;
    HANDLE kSnap;
    kPE32.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32W);
    kSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
    if (!kSnap)
        return NULL;
    if (Process32FirstW(kSnap, &kPE32))
    {
        do {
            if (kPE32.th32ProcessID == kPid)
            {
                wchar_t *kExe = kPE32.szExeFile;
                CloseHandle(kSnap);
                return kExe;
            }
        } while (Process32NextW(kSnap, &kPE32));
    }
    CloseHandle(kSnap);
    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    try
    {
        SetConsoleTitleW(L"BruteID");
        std::cout << R"(Press any key to start scanning for process IDs. . .)";
        getchar();

        DWORD kFirst = 0x0;
        int64_t kCount = 0;
        for (kFirst; kFirst < 10000; ++kFirst)
        {
            kCount++;
            wchar_t *kName = zGetName(kFirst);
            if (kName != 0)
            {
                std::cout << "{" << __TIME__ << "} " << "The process ID " << kFirst << " belongs to the process ";
                _tprintf(TEXT("%s"), kName);
                std::cout << "\n";
                zSetConsole(kCount);
            }
            else
                zSetConsole(kCount);
        }
    }
    catch (...) {}

    getchar();
}
```

Basically I am trying to check all the process IDs with an extremely simple 'for' loop and get the names of those that exist, but instead of the text I am getting something like 0D45FBA, etc.

I tried a lot of things and this code is just the last thing that I tried without success, I am looking for help.

Also tried to chance from UNICODE to Multi-Byte and vice-versa and many other things.

Comment: Have you tried with the "long" modifier`l`? As in `"%ls"`? Or use `std::wcout` to output the wide-character string?

Comment: Yes but I just get gibberish, I am starting to think the error may be from my zGetName function, but I can't spot anything

Comment: That is another problem, and comes from you returning a pointer to local data in the `zGetName` function. Perhaps use `std::wstring` as the return type?

Comment: My compiler is having a lot of trouble working with wstring, I don't think this will do it

Comment: @Aixiom What do you mean by that? Which compiler are you using?

Comment: I am using the VS2015 IDE, its compiler seems to screw things up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you had two problems:

1. Returning a pointer to a local variable that goes out of scope.
2. Printing a wide string as a narrow string.

This does what you're looking for. I copied the name into a `std::wstring` and returned it, and I used `std::wcout` to print the results.

I tested it successfully using Visual Studio 2015 and 2017 Community editions with no trouble.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <TlHelp32.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

std::wstring zGetName(DWORD kPid)
{
    std::wstring ret;

    if (kPid)
    {
        PROCESSENTRY32W kPE32;
        kPE32.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32W);
        HANDLE kSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
        if (kSnap)
        {
            if (Process32FirstW(kSnap, &kPE32))
            {
                do
                {
                    if (kPE32.th32ProcessID == kPid)
                    {
                        ret = kPE32.szExeFile;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                while (Process32NextW(kSnap, &kPE32));
            }
            CloseHandle(kSnap);
        }
    }
    return ret;
}

int main()
{
    for (DWORD kFirst = 0; kFirst < 10000; ++kFirst)
    {
        std::wstring kName = zGetName(kFirst);
        if (!kName.empty())
        {
            std::wcout << L"[" << std::setw(4) << kFirst << "] - " << kName << L"\n";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Example output:

```
[   4] - System
[ 340] - winlogon.exe
[ 368] - smss.exe
[ 560] - svchost.exe
[ 636] - csrss.exe
[ 728] - wininit.exe
[ 736] - csrss.exe
[ 740] - conhost.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside `wchar_t *zGetName(DWORD kPid)`, you are copying and then returning a pointer to the string `kPE32.szExeFile`, but `kPE32` is a local variable. It gets discarded after the function ends, so you have a pointer to invalid memory. It is not surprising that it points to random garbage.

You need to copy that string into new memory, that stays valid after the function ends, or provide target memory to the function to copy it in.